# Reset time / date to current time-zone using timedatectl preferably, or date

Tags: centos, date, timezone

I'm looking to reset the current system time to the selected time-zone using the timedatectl preferably, or date command. This is on the CentOS 7 OS, hence the timedatectl preference.

I'm in need of this for a practice lab in the lead up to my RHCSA exam. No where does the lab mention the use of ntp to achieve it. I'm able to manually set the time, but of course that's not guaranteed to be 100% accurate.

Does anyone know of a way to do this? I've trawled the web, as well as my study book / system docs to no prevail.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear: do you want to set the *time* or the *timezone*? “reset the current system time to the selected time-zone” — the value of the system time is independent of the timezone that it's displayed in.

Comment: Hi Gilles, I do apologise for not responding quicker, as I've been off-island for the past few weeks with no web access. I'm wanting to reset the current system time to the timezone of where I'm located. So, I've set my timezone as Europe/London, but this doesn't automatically update the system time. I'm looking to reset the system time/date to that of the timezone I've put the system in.

Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Still not clear. Changing the timezone doesn't affect the system time (which operates from an absolute origin — UTC), only the way it's displayed. If you want to change the time because it was wrong, just set the time — or let ntpdate do it for you (ntpd won't because it considers a large time difference to be a misconfiguration, but if you first set the time to within a few minutes then ntpd will make the clock converge to the right time). What is the actual problem? Programs displaying the wrong time? Programs displaying the correct time in the wrong timezone? Is the time correct or not?

Comment: My RHCSA lab is asking me to manually manipulate the system time, demonstrating knowledge of the date and timedatectl commands. However it then wants me to revert the changes and restore the system to the original time - it doesn't mention using ntp to achieve this. I'm now trying to find a way of using date or timedatectl to reset the time back to an accurate value corresponding with the real world time in London (as I'd assume that's what the original time will be as my exam is based there).

Thanks for your assistance in this.